# Merchant Cash Advances?

Tags: halacha, money, lending-interest-ribbis

I've heard recently of a relatively new practice of small business loans called Merchant Cash Advances. Wikipedia explains how it works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_cash_advance) and goes through some of the legalese to demonstrate the loophole that allows purveyors of this practice to avoid usury laws and oversight.

I'm not at all a maven in business nor in *ribbis* but I was wondering if there's any literature in halacha that deals with this practice or something similar. From a legalistic standpoint it's legit albeit shady but to my untrained sensibilities it carries a whiff of dishonesty and perhaps *avak ribbis* if not actual *ribbis*.

Thoughts, sources?

Comment: Reading the wikipedia article, I do not see how interest is charged. If set up properly, it **might** be lik a heter iskah of a type, but I cannot tell from the what the article is written. It could also be ribbis.

Comment: Hence my question. According to secular law the MCA does not qualify as a loan in the traditional sense making it not covered under typical usury laws. However, the merchants do charge more than the loan itself in their payback and they make a tremendous profit from these "loans". Bllomberg had an article of two ex-yeshiva guys living a life of debauchery after striking the mother lode using this practice; from their article it sounds like they take advantage of desperate small business owners who are otherwise ineligible for standard business loans.

Comment: Wikipedia describes the lender as paying the businessman a fixed amount in exchange for a (larger) fixed amount taken from credit-card sales. It doesn't, however, describe what happens if there are insufficient future credit-card sales to repay the agreed-upon amount. Does the lender lose out, then, or does the businessman need to repay by other means? I have a feeling (not that I know much at all about _hilchos ribis_) that the answer to that question may be relevant.

Comment: @msh210 there's no re-course. Once the borrower defaults (doesn't pay back for whatever reasons) you've got no way of getting your "Principal + Interest" back from the borrower.